# Smoothness in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Embarrasingly simple question, but I got the feeling that I cannot see the forrest for the trees right now:

If I have a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and want to show that it is in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$, is it enough to show that $\forall (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ the functions restricted to one of the parameters, $f_x: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, t \mapsto f(x, t)$ and $f_y: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, t \mapsto f(t, y)$ are in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$?

I have a gut feeling that this could be problematic, but I can't seem to construct a counterexample. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It’s been too long since I last taught multivariable calculus, but I think $f(x,y)=xy/(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$, $f(0,0)=0$, is the counterexample you're looking for, since when restricted to the axes it’s constant zero, while the function as a whole is not differentiable at the origin.

Comment: Heuristically, if you want to talk about differentiability at a point then you need to know something about $f$ on an open neighborhood of that point. So just looking at $f$ restricted to the coordinate axes can't give it too you.

Comment: @Lubin: Ah yes, of course. Do you want to turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: but if all the partial derivatives exist and are continuous in a neighbourhood of a point, then the function is C1 in a neighbourhood of that point.

Answer (score 2):

This question was answered in the comments.

> ... I think $f(x,y)=xy/(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$, $\,f(0,0)=0$, is the counterexample you're looking for, since when restricted to the axes it’s constant zero, while the function as a whole is not differentiable at the origin.
>
> –  Lubin Jan 18 '13 at 17:41